# FileNotFoundError in fastai.vision.all.ImageDataLoaders.from_df()

Tags: python, classification, fast-ai

I need a help. I am trying to load images for classification.

I wrote code in the picture bellow and it is giving a FileNotFoundError, even though the image is in the folder. The error was ** FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/kaggle/input/zindidata/images/9ea16180c50d0cd539897eefbfe585314e50a56b.jpg'
**

[image: Error]